# Ext 4.2.1 loading PHP-generated XMLfile with AJAX XML Reader

Tags: xml, extjs

My goal is to load XML to Store in Ext JS, then display the data in the grid.

I've prepared PHP that generates XML data

```
<?php
/** create-xml.php */
$books = [
  [
    "isbn"  => "9780071799355",
    "title" => "Oracle Database 12c SQL",
    "author" => "Jason Price"
  ],
  [
    "isbn"  => "0672328666",
    "title" => "Sams Teach Yourself Oracle PL/SQL in 10 Minutes",
    "author" => "Ben Forta"
  ]
];

$dom = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

$root = $dom->createElement("books");
$dom->appendChild($root);

foreach ($books as $b) {
  $book  = $dom->createElement("book");
  $isbn  = $dom->createElement("isbn", $b["isbn"]);
  $book->appendChild($isbn);
  $title = $dom->createElement("title", $b["title"]);
  $book->appendChild($title);
  $author = $dom->createElement("author", $b["author"]);
  $book->appendChild($author);
  $root->appendChild($book);
}

//$dom->formatOutput = true;
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Obviously, I checked the file create-xml.php generates XML on the localhost

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books><book><isbn>9780071799355</isbn><title>Oracle Database 12c SQL</title><author>Jason Price</author></book><book><isbn>0672328666</isbn><title>Sams Teach Yourself Oracle PL/SQL in 10 Minutes</title><author>Ben Forta</author></book></books>
```

I try to load it in the JS Script that relies on ext-all-dev.js.

```
var xmlbookStore = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
  fields: ["isbn", "author", "title"],
  autoLoad: true,
  proxy: {
    type: "ajax",
    url: "create-xml.php",
    //url: "books.xml",
    reader: {
      type: 'xml',
      record: 'book',
      rootProperty: 'books',
      idPath: 'isbn'
    }
  }
});

console.log(xmlbookStore);

Ext.onReady(function () {
  var grid = Ext.create("Ext.grid.Panel", {
    store: xmlbookStore,
    title: "Books",
    columns: [
      {
        text: "ISBN",
        dataIndex: "isbn"
      },
      {
        text: "Author",
        dataIndex: "author"
      },      
      {
        text: "Title",
        dataIndex: "title"
      }
    ],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
  });
});
```

What i find strange, the exact same code works when I switch the data source to ordinary XML-file 'books.xml' (generated from the same data and saved to disc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

When you use XML Reader it is necessary your server response to sent back data in XML format. I don't know if this is the best possible approach, but you may try with this (one additional line in your `create-xml.php` file):

```
<?php
...

header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```